# Entity with Inner class for building the entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I am trying out one-to-one mapping in JPA,
here i have taken relationship between Student and Contact, each student has an contact.

i have create Student entity as follows,

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TBL_STUDENT")
public class Student  implements  Serializable{

   public Student(){ }
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name="ID")  
   private Integer studentId;

   @OneToOne(targetEntity=StudentContact.class,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name="CONTACT_ID")
   private StudentContact contact;
   ....
   ....
   ....
}
```

Now the StudentContact entity as follows,

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TBL_STD_CONTACT")
public class StudentContact extends Serializable{
     public StudentContact(){ }

     @Id
     @Column(name="ID")
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     private Integer contactId;
     ...
     ...
     // all the properties mapped,

     public static class Builder{
         private Integer contactId;
         private String phoneNo;
         private String streetAddr;
         ....
         // all the properties as same as StudentContact

         public Builder(String val){
            this.city = val;
         }

         public Builder setContactId(Integer contactId) {
            this.contactId = contactId;
            return this;
         }

         // rest all the setter methods are like the above, having return type Builder

         public StudentContact build(){
              return new StudentContact(this);
         }
     }

     private StudentContact(Builder builder){
            this.contactId = builder.contactId;
            this.city = builder.city;
            this.phoneNo = builder.phoneNo;
            .......
            ...
     }
}
```

In the above StudentContact Entity you can see i have created an inner class Builder, whose responsibility is to build StudentContact object by using its "build" method, which you can see in below mentioned StudentTest class

Now i have written a StudentTest class which has the main method as follows,

```
public class StudentTest {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        try{
             StudentDAO dao = new StudentDAO();
             Student student = dao.getEntity(110);  
             StudentContact contact = new StudentContact.Builder("Bhubaneshwar")
                                      .setPhoneNo("9867342313")
                                      .setPinCode("400392")
                                      .setState("Odhisha").build(); 

             student.setContact(contact);
             dao.updateEntity(student);
           }catch(Exception e){
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
}
```

When i run StudentTest from netbeans IDE, it gives as error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Constructor must call super() or this() before return in method com.entities.StudentContact.<init>()V at offset 0
```

I am not able to understand this error, whether this error is because for the inner class which i have created in StudentContact class,

How can i solve this,

Comment: Even if i wrote super() or this() in my private Constructor of StudentContact still it gives an error

Comment: You have other problems; StudentContact _extends_ Serializable is one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`java.lang.VerifyError` means that the bytecode is not correct. Usually it can be fixed with a full clean/rebuild of the project. (I sometimes saw it after package/class renaming, or class moving from one package to another).

As mentionned in comments : `extends Serializable` is not correct. (maybe the cause of your bytecode issue ?)